# How to display specific range of number in Vue Js when making a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, frontend, vuejs2

How can I get specific number when I make a loop, in my case I want only to get **5** and above numbers or within a range that I want.

```
<select name="" id="input" class="form-control" v-model="selectcompetitionyear">
    <option v-for="n in 8" :value="n">Previous {{n}} games</option>
</select>
```

Result would be

```
<select name="" id="input" class="form-control" v-model="selectcompetitionyear">
    <option value="5">Previous 5 games</option>
<option value="6">Previous 6 games</option>
<option value="7">Previous 7 games</option>
<option value="8">Previous 8 games</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In v-for are you looping through a fixed number or you have an array?

Comment: I thought you can do a range like v-for="n in [5, 8]", but I figured out it now by using {{ n + 5 }}. Now it displays the numbers I needed.

Comment: @PenAndPapers, please post it as an answer, for the benefit of others :)

Comment: @PenAndPapers so is your problem solved?

Comment: yes I solved it @user7814783

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on use case, but one of methods would be:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
    data: {
        selectcompetitionyear:5
    },
    methods:{
        getNumbers:function(start,stop){
            return new Array(stop-start).fill(start).map((n,i)=>n+i);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="l-container l-vPad--mid">
    <select name="" id="input" class="form-control" v-model="selectcompetitionyear">
    <option v-for="n in getNumbers(5,9)" :value="n">Previous {{n}} games</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

My solution was just to add a number on the current loop value

```
<select name="" id="input" class="form-control" v-model="selectcompetitionyear">
    <option v-for="n in 5" :value="n+5">Previous {{ n + 5 }} games</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to control the step, you could use the following:

```
<option v-for="n in getNumbers(5,25,5)" :value="n">{{ n }}</option>

methods: {
      getNumbers:function(start,stop,step = 1){
        return new Array(stop / step).fill(start).map((n,i)=>(i+1)*step);
      },
}
```

And the result would be:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use v-if inside the option loop:

```
<option v-for="n in 8" v-if="n >=5" :value="n">Previous {{n}} games</option>
```